# Manual or Automatic transmission: Do rental companies let you choose which type of car you want to rent?

Tags: car-rentals, brazil

Say I'm a foreigner renting a car in Brazil.
What kind of car transmissions are popular in Brazil rental car agencies?
Do they let you choose if you ask?

I know standard (aka manual) transmission is, well, the most "standard" or popular type of car everywhere except the US, but in case I want to split driving with someone else who doesn't know how to drive one...

Comment: Tip I heard from a guy who used to work for a rental company, if not in Brazil, if you prefer a certain type of fuel, do indicate that when booking a reservation.

Comment: @Willeke Fuel? Do you mean transmission?

Comment: No, I mean fuel, like petrol/gas, diesel, lpg. I am not sure it makes a difference in Brazil, ie whether cars on other than petrol/gas are available, but in Europe there often is the choice and people do often prefer one over the other.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[According to TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g303576-i6938-k4958942-Rent_a_car_with_automatic_gearbox-Florianopolis_State_of_Santa_Catarina.html) it's rare to get  automatic transmissions in Brazil, or that when the companies do have them, they're regularly more expensive.

Your best bet is to contact the company before you get to Brazil (from comments of yours on other questions I gather you've booked through Modiva), and find out if you can reserve one.  I suspect they'll be getting similar questions from others, especially from the US, so should be able to clarify.

Comment: So this is how you got 70k+ pts, by answering questions faster than Flash can run! ;) thank Mark, always great info from you!

Answer (score 4):

Well, in Brazil you can get automatic transmission, and like @Mark said, it's more expensive. However, be advised when rent "popular" models with manual transmission. In general, the most cheap models **are insecure** (no ABS, no air-bags...).

There are some companies you can contact:

- [Avis](http://www.avis.com.br/b2c/pages/pesquisa_reserva)
- Locaralpha
- Mistercar
- [Localiza](http://www.localiza.com/)

Comment: [Unidas](http://site.unidas.com.br/)